# Can't type lowercase Q after switching to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

Sorry if my english isn't perfect but I am Italian.

I switched yesterday to Ubuntu 11.10 from 10.04 and I can't type lowercase Q. The strange thing is that if I enter as a guest I can type it, and Ubuntu even seems quicker.

I searched everywere in the net and I couldn't find anything. I yet checked out shorcuts like "ctrl+Q" but even if I disable it little Q just do not work. If I have to log in in Ubuntu I see that I can type it in the password. I do not know what to do, is it better to re-install  everything?

One other thing: before I couldn't see some icons, like "home" and a few others...then, by opening the guide they just appeared, as the icon for arresting the system high on the right (the one you press to turn the computer off) that wasn't there before.

But not letter Q. Seems that the guest version works better then the other, but I need mine. Anyone may help me? Just tell me if it's better for me and my pc to re-install everythingthank you. I can't help you with Ubuntu but I may help you in some other way, like teaching a little italian or giving you some good recipe ;)

Comment: Check your keyboard mapping. Its likely a language or kbd mapping setting...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!